# An efficient algorithm to decide if a triangulation is 3-colourable

Tags: algorithms, graphs, colorings

I don't know how to start with the following exercise:

> Design an efficient algorithm to decide whether a given triangulation with $n $ points is $3$-colourable.
>   The triangulation is given by a sorted edge list, where every edge is given by the indices of its two end points. Further, for every edge there are given the indices of the points with which the edge forms a triangle in the triangulation (two indices for interior edges and one index for edges on the boundary of the convex hull). Give proof for the correctnesss of your algortihm.

Below is an example.

I've heard about the BFS and DFS algorithms in lecture, but I don't see how I could apply this here. I'd be thankful for any help.[image]

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Not necessarily, every triangle must be colored with at least 3 different colours and it doesn't seem so far-fetched that 3 colours suffice unless we can find some obvious counter-example (such as in the picture). Plus, the exercise implies that it lies in P, so I'd bet there's some trick here.

Comment: Deciding whether a planar graph is 3-colorable is NP-hard. This is quite close to the problem at hand.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  Academia.SE has had a bunch of questions about that recently.

Comment: Yes it is, but I couldn't find anything similiar to this exercise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us assume that the dual graph is connected, which means that if you connect any two faces which share an edge, then you get a connected graph on the triangular faces.

Pick an arbitrary triangular face $F$ and color its 3 vertices with 3 distinct colors. If $F'$ shares an edge with $F$, then there is only one choice for the color of the remaining vertex of $F'$. Continuing in this way, attempt to color all vertices. If you're successful, the graph can be 3-colored. Otherwise, the graph cannot be 3-colored.

This algorithm is very similar to the one for deciding whether a given graph can be 2-colored.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is one point I don't get: How do you obtain the dual graph beforehand from the given list of edges?

Comment: You don't. You start with an arbitrary triangle (which you can find by picking a vertex and going over all pairs of neighbors), and then you repeatedly locate a vertex which forms a triangle with two of the vertices of the current triangle. This algorithm runs in time $O(n^2)$. Using more sophisticated approaches you can probably go down to $\tilde{O}(n)$.