# An efficient way to get the dual graph from a triangulation

Tags: algorithms, graphs

An answer to a [previous question I asked](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/86792/an-efficient-algorithm-to-decide-if-a-triangulation-is-3-colourable) advised me to find the dual graph of a triangulation.  I'm given the graph in the following form:

[image]

How can I get the dual graph from a list of edges given this way?

Comment: Don't forget that it's *you* who are supposed to solve the exercise. You won't learn anything if you let us solve all your exercises.

Comment: If it's just the way that you've been given the edge list that's confusing you, you could convert it to any format you want (e.g., adjacency list, adjacency matrix) pretty quickly. If you did that, would you know how to find the dual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the triangulation is given to you encapsulates this information, since along with each edge you are given the triangles it is part of. This allows you to reconstruct the edges of the dual graph (and from them, the vertices).

You can also recover this information, at higher cost, if the triangulation is given to you as a graph. In polynomial time you can, for example, find all triangles (the vertices of the dual graph) and all pairs of triangles intersecting at an edge (the edges of the dual graph). You can do it naively in $O(n^4)$, though I'm sure this can be brought down significantly, perhaps even all the way to $\tilde{O}(n)$.